mysql: insert sql was committed but data is not visible immediately
I use MWAA to run my SQL jobs, which are executed on RDS MySQL Community. For example, I start with job 'A', and once it's completed, I proceed to run job 'B'.
In job 'A', I use insert SQL to insert data into 'a_table'. After completion, job 'B' SQL queries the data inserted into 'a_table' by job 'A' and then inserts it into 'b_table'.
Currently, I've observed that although job 'A' has completed and committed, for instance, inserting 10 records into 'a_table', logically job 'B' should retrieve those 10 records and insert them into 'b_table'.
However, sometimes it fails to retrieve all records; it might only fetch 8 records and insert them into 'b_table'. Yet, if I manually rerun job 'B' for the same DAG run later on, it successfully retrieves all 10 records from 'a_table'.
So, I'm quite certain it's not an SQL issue but rather a problem occurring when running job 'B', where at times, not all 10 records from 'a_table' are written into 'a_table', even though job 'A' has completed successfully.
a job sql:
INSERT INTO a_table (
      DAG_START_TIME
    , DAG_END_TIME
    , A
    , B
    , C
    , UPDATE_TIME
)
SELECT
      %(start)s AS DAG_START_TIME
    , %(end)s AS DAG_END_TIME
    , A
    , B
    , C
    , UPDATE_TIME
FROM ABC
WHERE `DAG_START_TIME` = %(start)s
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      `UPDATE_TIME` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)
;

b job sql:
INSERT INTO b_table (
      DAG_START_TIME
    , DAG_END_TIME
    , A
    , B
    , C
    , UPDATE_TIME
)
SELECT
      %(start)s AS DAG_START_TIME
    , %(end)s AS DAG_END_TIME
    , A
    , B
    , C
    , UPDATE_TIME
FROM a_table
WHERE `DAG_START_TIME` = %(start)s
;

I've checked RDS CPU Utilization and Write Latency, both of which are well below threshold levels.
Is there any advise on how to address this issue? It will help me a lot.

Asynchronous behavior of committed transactions can may cause delayed visibility and job B might not see all the records immediately. still make sure that job A is fully committed before B starts

You can add a delay or wait between A and B to make sure the data committed by A is fully visible by B

You can also increase your transaction isolation level. the default is usually REPEATABLE READ , you might want to try READ COMMITTED


If you want to take it steps further you can consider:

Implementing a data validation logic [in B you can perform validation check if expected number of records is retrieved - if not, retry data retrieval again after a short wait ]
Tune your MySQL configuration [parameters like innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit or sync_binlog can influence transaction durability and visibility]


The transaction isolation level of the RDS is READ-COMMITTED.
sync_binlog is set to 1, and innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit is not configured. Do you have any recommendations on how to adjust the 'innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit' parameter?

0: Logs are written to disk every second but not flushed[Transactions are not durable in case of a crash] | 1: Logs are written and flushed to disk at each commit[slower due to frequent disk writes but ensures maximum data safety and consistency] | 2: Logs are written to disk at each commit but flushed only once per second[In case of a crash, you may lose the last second of transactions] ---------- to maximize reliability and consistency of data visibility 1 is the way to go even though it will slow the system when the load is high

as for how to change it, it should be similar to sync_binlog. create custom parameter group in RDS console - modify innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit to 1 in the new group and - apply the custom group to RDS instance via modify - save the changes

"Asynchronous behavior of committed transactions" where is such a thing stated? ACID demands that the database not confirm the commit until the data can be viewed by a later transaction.

To be acid compliant, in your RDS Parameter Group,
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1  # to ensure you are ACID compliant, for the safest and most reliable setting.

The BEST always and sometimes you may find the recording of the data is not
instantaneous.  MySQL has many things to accomplish in every second of uptime.
